# POSIX Signals does not get always get handled

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, signals, posix

I am trying to design and implement a simulation for a making an exam through
POSIX processes and Inter-Process Communication Techniques. The simulation
works as follows:

1. A process named Teacher will manage the whole simulation from the
   beginning till the end.
2. Teacher process uses fork/exec system calls to generate/load 10 Student
   processes.
3. Each Student process:

   a. waits a SIGNAL from the Teacher to start their exam.

   b. Once the Student receives a SIGNAL, it will start its exam.

   c. The Student process will invoke sleep system API to sleep a random
   number selected between [10 – 30] seconds, in order to emulate
   different times for finishing the exam among different processes.

   d. Once the sleep is over for that process it will trigger a SIGNAL that it
   has finished the exam
4. The Teacher process will keep tracking the order of Student processes that
   have finished.
5. At the end of all Student processes, the Teacher process will announce the
   results of the exam as follows and terminate.

Exam is over -> RESULTS ARE:

Student of ID=4128 Finished First

Student of ID=4122 Finished Second

Student of ID=4126 Finished Third
...

I have made this code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<signal.h>

static int child_recieved_sig = 0;
static int parent_recieved_sig = 0;
static int pids[10];
static int pidIndex = 0;

int random_time() {
    // generate random time from 10-30 sec
    srand(time(NULL) + getpid());
    int rand_time = (rand() % 21) + 10; //form [0-20]+10
    return rand_time;
}

//signal sent from the parent to the child to start the exam
void start_signal(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGUSR1) {
        child_recieved_sig = 1;
    }
}

//signal sent from the child to the parent indicating that the exam is over
void finish_signal(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* context) {
    if (sig == SIGUSR2) {
        parent_recieved_sig++;
        pids[pidIndex] = info->si_pid;
        pidIndex++;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction ss = { 0 }; // fs = start signal
    ss.sa_sigaction = start_signal;
    ss.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &ss, NULL);

    struct sigaction fs = { 0 }; // fs = finish signal
    fs.sa_sigaction = finish_signal;
    fs.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &fs, NULL);

    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) { //generate 10 children
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
            perror("Forking has Failed!");
        else if (pid == 0) { //child process
            while (child_recieved_sig != 1); // wait for signal
            printf("My ID is %d and I started my exam\n", getpid());
            int time_interval = random_time();
            printf("SleepTime: %d<-----------------------\n", time_interval);
            sleep(time_interval);
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            printf("Student %d finished exam\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        } else {
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }

    while (parent_recieved_sig < 10) usleep(50000);

    printf("parent_received_sig: %d\n", parent_recieved_sig);
    printf("The Exam is Over ==> Results are:\n");
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished First\n", pids[0]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Second\n", pids[1]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Third\n", pids[2]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Forth\n", pids[3]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Fifth\n", pids[4]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Sixth\n", pids[5]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Seventh\n", pids[6]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Eighth\n", pids[7]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Nineth\n", pids[8]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Tenth\n", pids[9]);
}
```

The problem is sometimes the code works and does the job as expected and other times without any modification to the code it gets stuck in the while look (`while (parent_recieved_sig < 10) usleep(50000);`), I have been trying to figure out the reason but i can't to come to a conclusion, I have tried printing the value of `parent_recieved_sig` sometimes it does not reach 10 meaning some signals have not been handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the other answer, non-real-time signals are not queued, thus you can miss some of them if they are sent *simultaneously* (from the OS point of view).

Below is your example slightly modified in order to replace the handling of `SIGUSR2` by the handling of `SIGCHLD`.
This signal is automatically sent to its parent when a child process terminates.

The interesting part is the signal handler which loops on `waitpid()` for any child process (`-1`) in a non-blocking fashion (`WNOHANG`) as long as this succeeds.
The handling of one `SIGCHLD` can lead to the detection of several simultaneous child-process terminations.

**EDIT1** As suggested in the comments, a more direct solution would be to get rid of the handling of `SIGCHLD` and modify the waiting loop in the `main()` function like this

```
    while (parent_recieved_sig < 10) {
        pid_t r=wait(NULL);
        if(r>0) {
            parent_recieved_sig++;
            pids[pidIndex] = r;
            pidIndex++;
        } else {
            perror("wait()");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2** As suggested in the comments, the global `int`s should be `volatile sig_atomic_t`s in order to be detected (not considered unchanged by the optimizer) by the main thread when modified by a signal handler.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#undef __STRICT_ANSI__ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

// ensure modifications in the signal handlers are detected
static volatile sig_atomic_t child_recieved_sig = 0;
static volatile sig_atomic_t parent_recieved_sig = 0;
static volatile sig_atomic_t pids[10];
static volatile sig_atomic_t pidIndex = 0;

int random_time(void) {
    // generate random time from 10-30 sec
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL) + (unsigned int)getpid());
    int rand_time = (rand() % 5) + 2; //form [0-20]+10
    return rand_time;
}

//signal sent from the parent to the child to start the exam
void start_signal(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* context) {
    (void)info;
    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1) {
        child_recieved_sig = 1;
    }
}

//signal sent from the child to the parent indicating that the exam is over
void finish_signal(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* context) {
    (void)info;
    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGCHLD) {
        for(;;) {
            pid_t r=waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
            if(r<=0) break;
            parent_recieved_sig++;
            pids[pidIndex] = r;
            pidIndex++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction ss = { 0 }; // fs = start signal
    ss.sa_sigaction = start_signal;
    ss.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &ss, NULL);

    struct sigaction fs = { 0 }; // fs = finish signal
    fs.sa_sigaction = finish_signal;
    fs.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &fs, NULL);

    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) { //generate 10 children
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
            perror("Forking has Failed!");
        else if (pid == 0) { //child process
            while (child_recieved_sig != 1); // wait for signal
            printf("My ID is %d and I started my exam\n", getpid());
            int time_interval = random_time();
            printf("SleepTime: %d<-----------------------\n", time_interval);
            sleep((unsigned int)time_interval);
            // kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            printf("Student %d finished exam\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        } else {
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }

    while (parent_recieved_sig < 10) usleep(50000);

    printf("parent_received_sig: %d\n", parent_recieved_sig);
    printf("The Exam is Over ==> Results are:\n");
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished First\n", pids[0]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Second\n", pids[1]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Third\n", pids[2]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Forth\n", pids[3]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Fifth\n", pids[4]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Sixth\n", pids[5]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Seventh\n", pids[6]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Eighth\n", pids[7]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Nineth\n", pids[8]);
    printf("Student ID=%d Finished Tenth\n", pids[9]);
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but do you see an advantage here to implementing a handler for `SIGCHLD` instead of the main process just calling `wait()` or `waitpid()` directly?  The latter seems more natural to me, especially since waiting for the children finish is exactly what the program wants to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger no, you are right, this was absolutely not necessary. I just wanted to stay as close as possible to the original example. For a totally different reason, I like this kind of solution because it enables waiting all the child-processes in a non-blocking fashion from the main thread point of view, when a solution à la `pthread_detach()` is to be considered but with processes.

Comment: `while (child_recieved_sig != 1);` is also problematic.  Given `static int child_recieved_sig = 0;`, a compiler would be free to replace that loop with an infinite loop, say something like `for (;;) ;`.  [You need to change the type to `volatile sig_atomic_t int`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p5)

Answer (score 3):

Only the real time signals are queued. The others can be merged. It's possible that two are sent and only one is received.

Comment: What you said is reasonable but is there a way I could fix this? like not allowing them to merge or something

Comment: Use `wait()` and handle the children exiting instead?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by using ```wait()```? because I waiting for the children to send the signals if 10 signals is sent this means all children have finished so I can stop looping in the while loop.

Comment: @Daniel, as you have discovered and as this answer explains, using signals to notify the parent of exam completions is simply not a viable solution if it is essential that no signals be lost.  The suggestion is that the children *not* signal the parent but instead simply terminate, and that the parent rely on the `wait()` function to recognize when children have done so.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: @Daniel Sure, if you use one of the RT signals it will work. Don't use them by number. They start at SIGRTMIN and go to SIGRTMAX. So SIGRTMIN+n, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @ZanLynx observes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66498762/2402272), regular signals are not queued, so if you rely on receiving signals from the children to recognize that they have finished then you are at risk of missing signals that arrive close together.

Furthermore, you are at fairly high risk of signals arriving close together because you are selecting from among just 21 possible delays for 10 different processes, so it is in fact very likely that there are pairs that have exactly the same delay (though that does not itself guarantee signal loss).  You could make that a lot less likely by employing a finer granularity for your delays, which you could achieve by using `nanosleep()` instead of `sleep()`.  That would not ensure that you do not miss signals, but it will make that less likely.

Better, however, would be to use a more reliable mechanism to recognize when the children finish.  Among the most natural alternatives would be the `wait()` function, as suggested in comments.